# how to write Android.mk files for multi-libs native c project?

Tags: c++, android-ndk, freetype

I have a **seGraphics** lib ,it deps **agg** lib and **freetype** lib.All of them are source files
I want to generate one **seGraphics.a** file.
Should i write a Android.mk file for each? How to write it?
TIA!

Here is my wrong try:

```
#Android.mk for seGraphics
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)
include $(CLEAR_VARS)

include $(LOCAL_PATH)/../../Agg/Android.mk

LOCAL_CXXFLAGS := -I../../

LOCAL_MODULE := seGraphics

LOCAL_SRC_FILES := ../../seCommonGradientBrush.cpp ../../seHatchBrush.cpp  

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

.

```
#Android.mk for agg
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

include $(CLEAR_VARS)

LOCAL_MODULE := agg

LOCAL_LDFLAGS :=  
LOCAL_CFLAGS := -O3

LOCAL_C_INCLUDES := ／home/maadiah/android-ndk-r6/platforms/android-9/arch-arm/usr/include \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/font_freetype \
        $(LOCAL_PATH)/gpc \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/include \
            $(LOCAL_PATH)/include/utils

AGG_SRCS := \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/font_freetype/agg_font_freetype.cpp \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/gpc/gpc.cpp \
    $(LOCAL_PATH)/src/*.cpp \

LOCAL_CPP_EXTENSION := .cpp     

include $(BUILD_STATIC_LIBRARY)
```

Comment: How can i cross compile the agg with freetype support?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found it best to build each lib independently (i.e. freetype and agg).  Then build seGraphics by linking against both freetype and agg using the following:  LD_FLAGS += -lfreetype -lagg.